# Lightning for outlook - Authentication each and every time for every mail

Tags: lightning-outlook

We have enabled the lightning for outlook. It is working great. Only thing that I am noticing is that for every mail when I click on salesforce icon, it does the authentication again and again which adds nearly 10 seconds delay to get the actual screen.

Is there any configuration which will make sure that user is logged in salesforce all the time. (It is ok if it does the authentication if the session time expires)?